# How to calculate field as cursor name?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, field-calculator

First time dealing with cursor.
I have lines intersecting polygons, I want to get a table with all attributes of the lines, add a field and calculate the field as the name of the polygon.
I was able to get a table for each polygon but I can't get to calculate the field and add the polygon name.
How do I do?
here is my code:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:\\Users\\a391665\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Default.gdb'
ws = 'C:\\Users\\a391665\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Default.gdb'
Comuni = 'C:\\Users\\a391665\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Sardegna3.gdb\\Comuni'
Linee = 'C:\\Users\\a391665\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Sardegna3.gdb\\Linee' 

rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(Comuni)

for row in rows:
    print row.NOME
    feat = row.Shape
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("Linee", "INTERSECT", feat, selection_type="NEW_SELECTION");
    out_feature_class = arcpy.ValidateTableName("Linee_Clip_" + row.NOME);
    table = arcpy.TableToTable_conversion("Linee", ws, out_feature_class);
    arcpy.AddField_management(out_feature_class, 'Clip', 'TEXT', '', '', '60');
    expression = arcpy.ValidateTableName(row.NOME);
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(table, "Clip", expression);
```

here is the error I get:

> Empty value for ObjectID = 1
>   The calculated value is invalid for the row with ObjectID = 1. For example, the calculated value may be too large for the field or you may be trying to add a string to a number field. This row will not be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:\\Users\\a391665\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Default.gdb'
ws = 'C:\\Users\\a391665\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Default.gdb'
Comuni = 'C:\\Users\\a391665\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Sardegna3.gdb\\Comuni'
Linee = 'C:\\Users\\a391665\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Sardegna3.gdb\\Linee' 

rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(Comuni)

for row in rows:
    print row.NOME
    feat = row.Shape
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("Linee", "INTERSECT", feat, selection_type="NEW_SELECTION");
    out_feature_class = arcpy.ValidateTableName("Linee_Clip_" + row.NOME);
    table = arcpy.TableToTable_conversion("Linee", ws, out_feature_class);
    arcpy.AddField_management(out_feature_class, 'Clip', 'TEXT', '', '', '60');

    rows2 = arcpy.UpdateCursor(table)
        for row2 in rows2:
        row2.Clip = str(row.NOME)
            rows2.updateRow(row2)
```

The second *for loop* goes through all the rows in the table and puts the value of row.NOME on the table's Clip column.

```
-----
```

```
Can you try this?

     expression = str(row.NOME);
     arcpy.CalculateField_management(table, "Clip", expression);
```

```
-------
```

```
I think an UpdateCursor would work.

    rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(Comuni)

    for row in rows:
        print row.NOME
        feat = row.Shape
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("Linee", "INTERSECT", feat, selection_type="NEW_SELECTION");
        out_feature_class = arcpy.ValidateTableName("Linee_Clip_" + row.NOME);
        table = arcpy.TableToTable_conversion("Linee", ws, out_feature_class);
        arcpy.AddField_management(out_feature_class, 'Clip', 'TEXT', '', '', '60');
        row.Clip = str(row.NOME)
        rows.updateRow(row)

It should be faster, too. From experience, the Calculate Field function can be rather slow.
```

Comment: Hi thank for your help;
I did as suggested but I get this error:
Runtime error <type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'>: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.

Comment: Oops. My bad, fixed my answer. instead of row.Clip = row.NOME, I set it to row.Clip = str(row.NOME)

Could you try it again?

Comment: no way, same error there.

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood your question. Will formulate a better answer.

Comment: btw if I open the table in ArcGIS and use field calculator str(row.NOME) works...

Comment: Can you try your original code but try changing expression to the one on my answer above the line?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4824/discussion-between-r-k-and-luca-moiana)